# Menu when in mobile will not scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on fixing a site that has been built by someone other than me. I am required to fix the menu scroll in mobile view. So far all I really know is that if you resize the browser then you are suddenly able to scroll, but if you are using a mobile then this is not the case. The site is called clasado.com If you change to mobile view by reducing your browser view port, then open the menu, you will see you can not scroll until you resize the browser. The javascript for this menu is as follows:

```
 /**
 * Navigation.js
 */
(function() {
    var Console = window.Console || (function() {
        return {
            name: function() { return "Console" },
            defaultConfig: function() { return this; },
            config: function() { return this; },
            to: function() { return this; },
            in: function(m) { console.log(m); return this; },
            out: function() { return this; },
            log: function(m) { console.log(m); return this; },
            reset: function() { return this; }
        }
    })();

    var search = {
        open: "[data-open]",
        toggler: ">a>[data-toggle]",
        group: "li > ul[data-collapsible]",
        collapsible: "[data-collapsible]",
        sidebarLeft: ".is-data .sidebar-left",
        sidebar: ".sidebar"
    }

    /**
     * The data-open attribute denotes that the menu block should open the sidebar
     */
    $(search.open).on("click", function(evt) {
        var sidebar = $(search.sidebar);
        var toggler = UUID.generateFor(this);

        var Log = toggler.data("log");

        if(window.handyHint) {
            handyHint.hide();
        }

        var isVertical = (function(sidebar, Log) {
            return function() { 
                Log.in("checkIfSidebarIsVertical");
                var isVertical = sidebar.find(".visible.vertical").css("display") !== "none"; 
                return Log.out(isVertical);
            }
        })(sidebar, Log);

        var sidebarControl = (function(sidebar, Log, isVertical) {
            return {
                /*
                 *  Check to see if the sidebar is currently open
                 */
                isOpen: function() {
                    return sidebar.data("open") === true && sidebar.hasClass("open");
                },
                isClosed: function() {
                    return sidebar.data("open") !== true && !sidebar.hasClass("open");  
                },
                /*
                 *  Opens the passed sidebar
                 */
                open: function() {
                    Log.in("sidebarControlOpen");

                    if(!!sidebar.data("open") === true) {
                        // Sidebar is already open
                        return Log.out(true);
                    }

                    if(isVertical()) {
                        sidebar.find("> .menu").slideDown(100);
                    }

                    sidebar.toggleClass("open");

                    $("<div></div>", { class: "nav-cover" }).appendTo("body").on( "click", this.close )

                    sidebar.data("open", true);
                    //docCookies.setItem("navbarOpen", true, null, "/", document.location.hostname, false);

                    return Log.out(true);
                },
                close: function() {
                    Log.in("sidebarControlClose");

                    if(!!sidebar.data("open") === false) {
                        // Sidebar is already closed
                        return Log.out(true);
                    }

                    if(isVertical()) {
                        sidebar.find("> .menu").slideUp();
                    }

                    var closed_left = sidebar.data("closed_left");

                    Log.log("left : " + closed_left);

                    sidebar.toggleClass("open");

                    $(".nav-cover").remove();

                    sidebar.data("open", false);
                    //docCookies.setItem("navbarOpen", false, null, "/", document.location.hostname, false);

                    return Log.out(true);
                }
            }
        })(sidebar, Log, isVertical);

        /* Only do anything if the sidebar exists */
        if(sidebar.isNotEmpty()) {
            Log.in("sidebarExists");

            if(sidebar.data("open")) {
                Log.in("isOpen");

                /* 
                 * If the sidebar is currently open, then it is important to 
                 * decide if the sidebar should just toggle to a different
                 * menu or be closed.
                 */

                if(!!toggler.data("open")) {
                    Log.in("hasStrip");

                    /* 
                     * Prevent the default action if the menu block is meant to
                     * open the sidbar
                     */

                     Log.log("Prevent default action");
                     // evt.preventDefault();


                    /*
                     * The toggler has a strip associated with it. Find the strip
                     * and use it to make a decision whether to open it or 
                     * to close it and the sidebar (if it was already open).
                     */

                    var area = toggler.data("open");
                    var menu_strip = $(".menu-strip." + area);

                    if(menu_strip.isNotEmpty()) {
                        Log.in("foundStrip");

                        var strip_was_open = !!menu_strip.hasClass("open");

                        var toggle = menu_strip.find(search.toggler);
                        if(toggle.isNotEmpty()) {
                            Log.in("foundToggle");

                            toggle.click();

                            Log.out();
                        }

                        if(strip_was_open) {
                            Log.in("stripWasOpen");

                            /*
                             * If the strip was open at the start of this check,
                             * then the sidebar needs to be closed.
                             */

                            sidebarControl.close();

                            Log.out();
                        } else {
                            Log.log("stripWasClosed");
                        }

                        Log.out();
                    } else {
                        Log.in("couldNotFindStrip");

                        sidebarControl.close();

                        Log.out();
                    }

                    Log.out();
                } else {
                    sidebarControl.close();
                }

                Log.out();
            } else {
                Log.in("isClosed");

                /*
                 * If the sidebar is closed, it needs to be opened. Then,
                 * if the data-open tag notes a submenu to open, that menu
                 * should be opened.
                 */

                // Store the current left offset so it can be returned to when closed
                var current_left = sidebar.find(search.sidebarLeft).css("left");
                if(!!sidebar.data("closed_left") === false) {
                    sidebar.data("closed_left", "-375px");
                }

                sidebarControl.open();

                if(!!toggler.data("open")) {
                    Log.in("hasStrip");

                    /* 
                     * Prevent the default action if the menu block is meant to
                     * open the sidbar
                     */

                    Log.log("Prevent default action");
                    evt.preventDefault();

                    /*
                     * If the menu block contains any information
                     * as to the menu to open, then it needs to be
                     * opened.
                     */

                    // Fetch the menu strip to be opened that's stored 
                    // on the toggler's data
                    var area = toggler.data("open");
                    var menu_strip = $(".menu-strip."+area);

                    if(menu_strip.isNotEmpty()) {
                        Log.in("foundStrip");
                        /*
                         * If the menu strip exists, then toggle it open
                         * by clicking on its toggle button.
                         */

                        var toggle = menu_strip.find(search.toggler);
                        if(toggle.isNotEmpty()) {
                            Log.in("foundToggle");

                            // As there is a toggle, click it.

                            toggle.click();

                            Log.out();
                        } else {
                            Log.in("noToggleFound");
                            Log.out();
                        }

                        Log.out();
                    }

                    Log.out();
                }

                Log.out();
            }
            Log.out();
        }
        Log.out();
    });

    /**
     *  Ready function to set up collapsible navigation objects
     */
    function ready() {
        $(".default-open").removeClass('default-open');
        $(search.collapsible).each(function() {
            /*
             * Set up the collapsing of each of the tagged elements
             */

            var toggle = UUID.generateFor(this);
            var Log = toggle.data("log");

            var parent = toggle.parent();
            var toggler = parent.find(search.toggler);

            toggler.on("click", function(evt) {                 
                Log.in("click");

                /*
                 *  If there is a drop down, then there needs to be a stop on any
                 *  attempt to send to a new page!
                 */
                Log.log("prevent default action");
                evt.preventDefault();

                if(toggle.data("collapsible") == "") {
                    Log.in("justCollapse");

                    var Toggle = {
                        getToggle: function(el) {
                            var Log = Console.to("Toggle").in("getToggle(" + UUID.get(el) +")");

                            var group_parent = el.parent();
                            var toggle = group_parent.find(search.toggler);
                            if(toggle.isNotEmpty()) { 
                                Log.log("foundToggle").out();

                                return toggle;
                            } else {
                                Log.log("noToggleFound").out();

                                return false;
                            }
                        },
                        open: function(el) {
                            var Log = Console.to("Toggle").in("open(" + UUID.get(el) +")");

                            if(!!el.data('open') == false) {
                                Log.in("canOpen");

                                el.slideDown(null, function() { myScroll.refresh(); });
                                el.parent().addClass("open");
                                el.data("open", true);

                                Log.out();
                            }

                            Log.out();
                        },
                        close: function(el) {
                            var Log = Console.to("Toggle").in("close(" + UUID.get(el) +")");

                            if(!!el.data('open') == true) {
                                Log.in("canClose");

                                el.slideUp();
                                el.parent().removeClass("open");
                                el.data("open", false);

                                Log.out();
                            }

                            Log.out();
                        },
                        toggle: function(el) {
                            var Log = Console.to("Toggle").in("toggle(" + UUID.get(el) +")");

                            if(!!el.data('open') == false) { 
                                Toggle.open(el); 
                            } else {
                                Toggle.close(el); 
                            }

                            Log.out();
                        }
                    }

                    if(!!toggle.data("open")) { 
                        Log.log("alreadyOpen");

                        Toggle.close(toggle);

                        Log.reset();
                        return;
                    }

                    Log.log("gettingGroup");
                    var group = toggle.parents("ul").first().find(search.group);
                    group.each(function(index) {
                        Log.in("processGroupIndex" + index);

                        var collapsible = $(this);
                        var last = (index == group.length - 1);

                        Toggle.close(collapsible);

                        if(last) {
                            Log.in("isLast");

                            Toggle.open(toggle);

                            Log.out();
                        }

                        Log.out();
                    });

                    Log.out();
                } else {                                                            
                    Log.in("collapseInto");

                    var menu_holder_collapsible = toggle.data("collapsible");

                    var menu_holder_class = menu_holder_collapsible.split(":")[0];
                    var index = menu_holder_collapsible.split(":")[1];

                    var menu_holder = $(".menu-holder." + menu_holder_class);
                    if(menu_holder.isNotEmpty()) {
                        Log.in("foundMenuHolder");

                        if(menu_holder.data("open")) {
                            Log.in("menuIsOpen");

                            var toggle_field = menu_holder.find(search.collapsible);

                            if(menu_holder.data("index") == index) {                    
                                Log.in("indexMatch");

                                toggle_field.first().slideUp(function() {               
                                    Log.in("emptyMenuHolder");

                                    menu_holder.empty();

                                    Log.out();
                                });

                                menu_holder.data("open", false);

                                Log.out();
                            } else {
                                Log.in("differentIndex");

                                var cloned_toggle = toggle.clone();
                                cloned_toggle.hide();

                                if(index > menu_holder.data("index")) {
                                    Log.in("indexGreaterThan");

                                    if(cloned_toggle.children().isNotEmpty()) { 
                                        menu_holder.append(cloned_toggle); 
                                    }

                                    Log.out();
                                } else {
                                    Log.in("indexLessThan");

                                    if(cloned_toggle.children().isNotEmpty()) { 
                                        menu_holder.prepend(cloned_toggle);
                                    }

                                    Log.out();
                                }

                                toggle_field.addClass("remove");

                                toggle_field.toggle(function() {
                                    Log.in("removeToggleField");

                                    menu_holder.find(".remove").remove();

                                    Log.out();
                                });

                                cloned_toggle.toggle("slide");
                                menu_holder.data("index", index);

                                Log.out();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.in("menuIsClosed");

                            var cloned_toggle = toggle.clone();
                            if(cloned_toggle.children().isNotEmpty()) {
                                cloned_toggle.hide();
                                menu_holder.html(cloned_toggle);
                                cloned_toggle.slideDown();
                                menu_holder.data("open", true);
                                menu_holder.data("index", index);
                            }

                            Log.out();
                        }

                        Log.out();
                    } else {
                        Log.log("cannotFindMenuHolder");
                    }

                    Log.out();
                }
                Log.reset();
            });
            Log.reset();
        });
    }

    $(window).load(ready);

})();
```

The CSS is unfortunately spread all over the place and would be a difficult process to consolidate. If you could check the site and get an idea of styles through inspecting the elements and see if you can find a javascript or css fix this would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your .sidebar is having position:fixed. This fixed it for me.Just remove this style on mobile and u may also want to reduce its height.

Comment: This partially works. However, once I click one of the menu items after doing this, the menu itself closes.

Comment: So dont only remove the position:fixed make it absolute,Relative is pushing items down and is breaking your navigation.